# JPA OneToMany Only Updates First Time

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink and I have two basic classes like

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id
  @Column(name="FOO_ID)
  private int id;
  
  @Column(name="FOO_NAME")
  private String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
  private List<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
  @Id
  @Column(name="BAR_ID")
  private it id;
  
  @Column(name="BAR_NAME")
  private String name;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="FOO_ID")
  private Foo foo;
}
```

Then I have some code which essentially does

```
public void processBar(Foo foo) {
  Bar bar = new Bar();
  bar.setName("Test");
  bar.setFoo(foo);
  entityMgr.persist(bar);
  
  List<Bar> bars = foo.getBars();
  
  for (Bar b : bars) {
    System.out.println("Bar - id : " + b.getId());
    System.out.println("Bar - name : " + b.getName());
  }
}
```

When I go in to the webapp and call the code (foo is set fine) then I can see the expected output of one child `Bar` with the id and name I expect.

If I then go into a new session and run the same code then instead of seeing two `Bar`s, I am still seeing the first one (and only the first one) but the `Bar` record is created in the database and is linked correctly.

If I add the same loop to print out bars prior to creating the new `Bar` then I always see an empty list both before and after creating `bar`

Setting `fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` on the `oneToMany` gives me the empty set.
Merging foo after adding bar doesn't make any difference.

What do I need to get this to be consistent?

**Update**

I do now have this working by implementing an `addBar` method in `Foo`

```
public void addBar(Bar b) {
  bars.add(b);
}
```

adding a cascade to the relationship

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

then I have replaced the `persist` of bar with `foo.addBar(bar)`

and finally added `entityMgr.merge(foo)`

This is now working as I expected but I still don't understand why the original code didn't work so that question still remains about how that code could work (or whether it has to be done as I have done here)

Comment: You should add correct cascades. In most cases, cascade = CascadeType.ALL works well on @OneToMany. In your case, you would need to persist Foo for that to work, not Bar.

Comment: Foo has come from `entityMgr.createQuery("select f from Foo")` so should already be managed?   I tried adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to the `OneToMany` and then replacing the persist on Bar to `entityMgr.merge(foo)` (I can't `persist` as a database record exists for that key but that doesn't create a database row for `Bar`.   Persisting bar and then merging foo doesn't work either

Comment: How is your transaction handling implemented? What do the logs say - if anything?

Comment: Transactions are handled by the EJB and I am not doing anything special.  Nothing is logged at all.   See update though as I do have it working but not sure if this is how I should be doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a bidirectional OneToMany Relation, as such, you are responsible for updating the Java model if you add or remove items from the relations, e.g by providing special setters. For an example, [see this blogpost](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/).

Comment: That is helpful.   What I don't get though is why this was working the first time?    Was that just because it was loaded the first time I accessed it (being lazy loaded) at which point the child record had been persisted.    After that the collection was managed so persisting new child records didn't show up.      If that is the case, why did merge on the parent not update the collection?

Comment: The first part about lazy loading sounds right to me. I think you are confused about what merge does, merge copies the state of the passed in entity to the Foo instance in the persistence context. As you pass in the same Foo instance, nothing happens. You should turn on SQL logging to verify your expectations vs what really happens.

Comment: I will turn on logging and see what is going on.    If I persist Foo then it tries to create a new database record and I get a primary key violation as a record obviously already exists with the same ID.    I guess this means my instance of Foo isn't actually managed as persist should update an existing managed entity?