# JPA Multiple Merges Causing Duplicate Records

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, lombok

## Issue

I have a one to many parent child relationship but when I merge the parent object it is creating a duplicate set of child records.

## Details

This is a follow on from [JPA OneToMany Only Updates First Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283457/jpa-onetomany-only-updates-first-time)
I am using Eclipse Link and following on from this I now have two classes that look like

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id
  @Column(name="FOO_ID)
  private int id;
  
  @Column(name="FOO_NAME")
  private String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Bar> bars;

  public void addBar(Bar b) {
    b.setFoo(this);
    bars.add(b);
  }

}

@Entity
public class Bar {
  @Id
  @Column(name="BAR_ID")
  private it id;
  
  @Column(name="BAR_NAME")
  private String name;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="FOO_ID")
  private Foo foo;
}
```

and then I have

```
public void processBars(Foo foo) {
  for (MyListItem i : myList) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setName("Test");
    foo.addBar(bar);
  }
  entityMgr.merge(foo);
}
```

and finally

```
processBars(foo);

if(someCodition) {
  foo.setStatus("xxx");
  entityMgr.merge(foo);
}
```

This second merge is then creating a second set of Bars

## Sequence, Id and EqualsAndHashCode

I am guessing this is down to the use of database sequences for the ID fields.   When `Bar` is created the ID is obviously null and then for some reason it is checking again after the record has been inserted and deciding it is a different object.  I am using `Lombok` and have added `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations to both classes excluding the list of children in 'Foo'

## Update

Reworked question as I figured out it was the second merge that is causing the problems

Answer (score 1):

JPA's merge api takes the object passed in and merges it into the context. This is different from persist, which takes the instance passed in and makes it managed - merge will return the managed instance.

```
Entity e = new Entity();

Entity e1 = em.merge(e);
assertTrue(e1!=e);// they are different instances
```

when the transaction is flushed/committed, e1 will have its ID set because it was managed by the persistence unit, but 'e' will not. So when you call em.merge(e), you are giving it a blank instance, forcing in duplicates.

Simple solution is to return the resulting Foo from your processBars method and use it for your subsequent changes and merge calls.

Comment: I figured as as it was the parent that was being merged and the equals / hash methods did not include the child collection that the merge should be able to tell they were the same but I guess the cascade it effectively calling merge on all the child elements too?
I actually ended up moving away from database sequences and using UUIDs (https://web.archive.org/web/20171211235806/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html) which solves the issue as JPA does realise they are the same objects

Comment: Fundamentally the issue is that I am calling merge twice on the same detached object right?   This detached object has the children (with no IDs) and does not get updated by the merge although the database does.   When the second merge comes along the instance I am merging still has children with no IDs so treats them as dirty and inserts new records.

Comment: Yes, merge is making copies of your initial object. Use the managed instance - it will have its ID set when the context is flushed or the transaction is committed, and there is no reason for JPA to have to remerge over and over into the same context object while the context is open and available. JPA has to go through all the mappings and compare changes each time you call merge, and even reads from the DB if the pk is involved- that is the only way for it to know if it is new or existing if you are assigning keys yourself.